# Pipeline - Redo a job sequence

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline like this :

1 - Standard Job Sequence

2 - Repair Job Sequence
(Already configured to run only if previous failed)

[image: Pipeline]

Is there a way to redo the first Sequence if the Repair Sequence succeed ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? As I understand from your question, you want always "green" pipeline. But then, what is the point of a pipeline if you dont have a failing one, and check what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I would like to compile and do some work in the first one. If it fail, i assume some packages or installations are missing, so i would like to run an installation sequence, then finally run again the compile sequence